# "Не найден дескриптор запуска компонента database engine" MS sql server 2012/2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

При установке Microsoft SQL server 2012 ближе к концу загрузки выпадает сообщение:

> Не найден дескриптор запуска компонента database engine.

Из-за этого сам сервер не запускается, работать невозможно. Как решить это?

P.S. Тоже самое появляется при установке  sql servel 2014.
P.P.S. Можно ли прочитать mdf базу на локальном компьютере без подключения к серверу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило, свидетельствует о несовместимости SQL Server'а и операционной системы.

Проверьте по требованиям, можно ли на вашу ОС установить SQL Server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx

По второму вопросу - mdf-файл не является базой - это один из файлов базы - как минимум, требуется еще ldf-файл, также возможно наличие ndf-файлов и Filesteam-каталогов.

И без наличия развернутого SQL Server'а открыть файл базы данных у вас не получится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня Windows 7, вроде поддерживается, тем более на другой  компьютер с семёркой поставил нормально.

Comment: Windows 7 - Это недостаточные сведения :) Нужна полная информация о версии SQL Server'а, и о версии Windows. Так, SQL Server Standard 2012 ставится только на Ultimate, Enterprise и Professional, а вот Developer и Express - еще и на Home Pemium и Home Basic. При этом обязательно наличие SP1.

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточность , да windows у меня Professional версия с Service Pack 1. Сервер Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express.Нигде нет решения этой проблемы. Очень печально.